# How to protect a third eye?

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, humanoid

Humans have 2 eyes, under a brow ridge. This ridge seems to have the purpose of protecting the eyes from sunlight. If a human-faced creature had a third eye, where could it be, while being able to link with the other eyes and being protected from sunlight?

Comment: just lengthen the face, lower the nose, thicken the ridge in the middle, and put the eye there. Also, a third eye is kinda useless and redundant on a humanoid face. Two eyes already provide all that you need.

Comment: @Firestryke On the face maybe, but only if we assume the third eye has the same properties as the other two. If it has different focal properties, reacts to different light spectra, etc. then it can still be useful.

Comment: @Corey just add extra visual sensitivity to the already existing eyes

Comment: @Firestryke You're assuming design. What if it just developed that way?

Comment: @Corey of course I am assuming design. We are literally designing it

Comment: @Corey also it is more likely to develop as the two eyes having additional functionality than it is to develop a whole new eye

Comment: @Firestryke And yet third eyes exist in several terrestrial species that could easily develop to provide separately from the primary eyes of those species. It's not like there's a goal or something, this isn't guided evolution.

Comment: Im not going to debate with you the possibility of evolution in this comment section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It probably wouldn't be linked with the other two eyes.

It's not uncommon for creatures to have third eyes. They're called parietal eyes, and grow from the pineal gland. They help with sensing temperature and position.

They could take on additional functions in a world of magic. Perhaps the pineal gland helps regulates responses to the supernatural and it could help them have better sensitivity to magic.

If you want them protected from sun and water you could have them on the nose, and have an elongated brow, similar to the above, but with a wider brow.

[image]

Or you could have them on the top of the head, to give better awareness upwards.

[image]

You don't need eyebrows. There are other options, like a skin layer covering the eye, to protect it.

Answer (score 10):

**The crown of the head.**

Let us figure this out starting with real physiology.  The pineal gland in humans is a light sensing organs in other vertebrates.  Retinoblastoma is a hereditary eye cancer in humans and some babies born with this predisposition develop [trilateral retinoblastoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateral_retinoblastoma) with a tumor in each eye and one in the pineal gland.  This image shows a tumor on the pineal gland (a different type) but is a good image to see the relationship between the pineal and the rest of the skull.

[image: pineal tumor]
http://www.pedsoncologyeducation.com/pinealtumorsradiology.asp

The pineal is pretty deep but it is right in the midline and there is nothing above it except the falx cerebri dividing the two halves of the cerebrum.

The third eye arising from the pineal could be directly under the [fontanelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontanelle).

[image: fontanelle]

This is the spot on the crown of the head where at birth the bones of the skull have not fused - the "soft spot".  As a baby grows these bones fuse to produce the dome of bone that is a human skull.  In your creatures with three eyes a hole remains in the bone (as it does for some humans!) and the third eye is under this hole in the bone.  Just as the orbits provide a ridge of bone to protect our two frontal eyes, the cranial bones will provide bone to protect the third eye on the crown.

In infants, there is skin over this hole and tissue as well.  This would allow an eye sited here to perceive light and dark.  I could imagine a more transparent covering of cartilage could let more light through.

As regards coordinating this eye with the others that would be done via the brain as with everything else in the body.  The field of view would be different that that of the two frontal eyes.

Comment: +1 for the cool info